# Spring&Hibernate paggination

Tags: spring, hibernate, pagination

i want to make pagination for my site (current just practice)
I using Spring and Hibernate. I understand that i can use Critera to retrive example 5 by 5 Person name. But how to send that to JSP page and make pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data for this:

```
interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {

}

@RestController
class BookController {
   @Autowired
   BookRepository bookRepository;

   @GetMapping("/books")
   public Page<Book> getAllBooks(Pageable pageable){
      return bookRepository.findAll(pageable);
   }
}
```

By adding `Pageable` to controller method Spring adds three request parameters: `page`, `size` and `sort`. And request will look like: `curl 'http://localhost:8080/books?page=0&size=20&sort=title%2Cdesc'` 
Spring automatically will create that Pageable object.

Spring Data can work with this object and returns `Page<T>` in response, which contains among requested entities (in `content` array) a lot of pagination information such as `totalPages`, `numberOfElements`.